# how to write hibernate criteria query for below SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

```
SELECT (Title + ' ' & Forename & ' ' & Surname) AS FullName FROM details;
```

or

```
SELECT (Title || ' ' || Forename || ' ' || Surname) AS FullName FROM details;
```

and also I want to use
hibernate projection for FullName

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question - but concatenation in java code outside the criteria is not a bad idea, helps separate data retreiving from business logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProjectionList if you want condition base projection e.g

```
ProjectionList prjection = Projections.projectionList();
if(abc){
    prjection.add(Projections.property("firstname"));
}
else if(xyz){
    prjection.add(Projections.property("Surname"));
}

    ........

    criteria.setProjection(prjection);
```

And if you want OR/And Condition in Criteria than you can use 
Junction invitationTypeNotJunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
Junction invitationTypeJunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

you can refer http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/RestrictionsDisjunction.htm link for more information